# ts-json-schema-generator, can the SchemaGenerator be used with an in-memory source file?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to use `SchemaGenerator` from `ts-json-schema-generator` with in-memory files or just the file content?

```js
const src = ts.createSourceFile(
  "test.ts",
  `type Schema = {
          images: {
              src: string;
              alt?: string;
          }[];
          fallbacks: Array<{ src: string; alt?: string }>;
      }`,
  ScriptTarget.ESNext
);

const config = {
  path: src.fileName,
  type: "Schema", // Or <type-name> if you want to generate schema for that one type only
};
const schema = createGenerator(config).createSchema(config.type);
```